# Django OperationalError: no such table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've ran all the commands under the sun to try and fix this which normally solve the problem but this time nothing is working.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
python manage.py migrate --fake users 
python manage.py migrate users 0012
```

I've read a few questions on SO and now think it has to do with something executing immediately when imported so the migration doesn't go through.

The only thing I've changed is added a new model `TextSubmission` and altered `views.py`. If someone could show me / identify the problematic code, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Unapplying users.0014_auto_20190314_1141...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users_textsubmission

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_backwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 196, in _migrate_all_backwards
    self.unapply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 262, in unapply_migration
    state = migration.unapply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 175, in unapply
    operation.database_backwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_backwards
    schema_editor.delete_model(model)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 290, in delete_model
    super().delete_model(model)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 331, in delete_model
    "table": self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: users_textsubmission
```

models.py

```
class TextSubmission(models.Model):
    text_submission    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    user                   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['text_submission']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text_submission
```

views.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        try:
           t_form = TextSubmissionForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.textsubmission)
        except TextSubmission.DoesNotExist:
           t_form = TextSubmissionForm(request.POST)

        if p_form.is_valid() and t_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            t_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        t_form = TextSubmissionForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form,
        't_form': t_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Comment: remove all row from `django_migrations` table in database then run migrations

Comment: Would that delete the data?

Comment: no. remember just delete from `django_migrations` table not the whole database

Comment: Why are you faking the users migration?

Comment: Hi @Trilla, have you ever managed to fix this issue?